# Best way to find/open files in Zathura

Tags: zathura

I like Zathura as a PDF reader quite a lot, but one feature I haven't found that I miss from other PDF readers is an easy way to open a file from within Zathura. The only way I know how to do this is by issuing an :open command, but to use that command I need to know the full path of the file I want to open (unless it's already in Zathura's history, in which case I can tab to it.) I typically end up just finding the file in the Shell, and then issuing the Zathura command from within the directory of the file I want to open. My question is, is there a better way to find a file from within Zathura itself (maybe something like :Explore in Vim?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#usage), i.e., a command line fuzzy finder. Once installed you can use

```
zathura $(fzf)
```

and then enter the file name (*fuzzily* if that's a word) you want to open. This is super fast and works well.

EDIT: Unfortunately, this approach leaves you with an open terminal in addition with the zathura window. To overcome this, you can use

```
nohup zathura $(fzf)
```

And I would like to close the terminal session right after zathura opens. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: do you know whether there is a way to do this inside zathura?

Answer (score 0):

[fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) is a good choice but since it leaves a terminal open, you'll have to use something like [xdo](https://github.com/baskerville/xdo) to show/hide the terminal.

I wrote a small script, [engulf.sh](https://github.com/shisui98/engulf.sh) that does both. It uses fzf to pick a file and uses xdo to "swallow" the terminal while zathura is open. Once zathura closes, the terminal reappears. Files can be selected from file managers like ranger too.